# Unable to search array field using Firestore's arrayContainsAny operator in Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, google-cloud-firestore

I need to search a field that contains an array of the types of a bunch of different animals (eg. Bears, Cats, Dogs, Snakes, Raccoons). I'll be searching for two or three animals each time (eg. Snakes and Raccoons". I'm familiar with the syntax for searching an array for a single animal, and when I do that it works fine:

```
db = Firestore.firestore()
let docRef = self.db.collection(“Animals")
let query = docRef.whereField("animal_types", arrayContains: “Rabbits")
//This works perfectly and returns all the records that contain rabbits
```

I see from the documentation that in order to search for multiple animals at a time I can use the arrayContainsAny operator, using the following syntax:

```
let query = docRef.whereField("animal_types", arrayContainsAny: [“Rabbits", “Raccoons"])
```

However, XCode is rejecting this operator, bringing up an error saying

> No exact matches in call to instance method 'whereField'

So my code can't even compile. I updated all the Firestore cocoapods to the latest version in case my version was too old and didn't have this feature, but no difference - the same error comes up every time. I'm using Swift 4 and XCode 11.6.

Edit: Here is a screenshot showing what happens when I try to enter either the arrayContainsAny operator or the in operator as was suggested - Xcode isn't even recognizing them as valid values  [image: these are the only valid options Xcode is recognizing]

As requested, here is the way my data is organized in Firestore. The Collection is called "Animals" and consists of documents with 2 fields - "animal_family" which is the scientific classification for the family the animal belongs to, and "animal_types" which will list the ordinary names for the types of animals that fall under that family. What I am trying to do is search the animal_types array field for multiple animal types (eg Rabbits and Raccoons as you see in my sample code) and have that return the matching documents.
[image]
[image]

Comment: What is 'animal_types'?  Is it a field?

Comment: yes, it's a field containing an array of strings - each string is a type of animal

Comment: Show your data tree at Firestore.  I think docRef is wrong.

Comment: I've added screenshots of the data

Answer (score 0):

Google documentation show Swift syntax as:

```
        // [START in_filter_with_array]
        docRef.whereField("animal_types", in: [["Rabbits"], ["Raccoons"]]);
        // [END in_filter_with_array]
```

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#swift_10

Comment: The documentation states that this syntax is for cases where the field will match either of the arguments, but in my case the field might have both. It turns out its moot anyway, as when I try to use this syntax it gives the same error. It seems my XCode is just not acknowledging these operators as valid arguments. When I start typing the operator and let the drop down autocomplete list appear, it shows the following operators - isLessThan, isGreaterThan, isLessThanOrEqualTo, isGreaterThanOrEqualTo, arrayContains. If I try to add any what aren't on that list the error comes back.

Comment: What version SDK are you using?  array-contains-any is fairly new...

Comment: I'm using Xcode 11.6 - so it's only a year old.

Comment: And which version of SwiftUI?  Which version of FirebaseFirestore?  Since the functionality is openly documented here:  https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasefirestore/api/reference/Classes/Query  , some part of your development environment is out of date.

Comment: I updated all the FIrestore and other cocoa pods to the latest versions, and I'm not using SwiftUI.

Comment: https://github.com/firebase/snippets-ios/blob/f3d37c59a3031cf0a7ae726ba3839cddae8eadea/firestore/swift/firestore-smoketest/ViewController.swift#L1086-L1087

Answer (score 0):

After I double checked everything, it turns out the version of the FirebaseFirestore cocoa pod was too old. I thought I had updated them when I first had the problem, but turns out I had cd'd to the wrong folder and had run pod update on a backup copy of the project. Thanks to everyone who gave suggestions, as eliminating those potential issues led me back to checking on the basics again.

Comment: Mark your answer as "answered" if you can